# Error in R Krig function in package fields

Tags: r

I am using package `fields` to do spatial analysis.

My data set is as follow:

```
               x     y
Kopenhagen  12,57 55,68
Rotterdam    4,48 51,92
Belgrade    20,46 44,82
Budapest    19,04  47,5
Dublin      -6,27 53,34
Rome        12,48 41,89
Lisbon      -9,14 38,71
Bucharest    26,1 44,45
Madrid       -3,7 40,42
Lausanne     6,63 46,52
London      -0,13  51,5
Kiel        10,13 54,33
Augsburg    10,89 48,36
Innsbruck  11,398 47,25
Helsinki    24,94 60,17
Lyon         4,83 45,77
Ngreece      22,5  41,5
Ancona      13,11 43,37
Forde         5,9 61,44
Warsawa     21,01 52,23
Uppsala     17,64 59,86
Barcelona    2,17 41,38
Prague      14,42 50,09
```

This is the output of

```
dput(map)

structure(list(x = structure(c(6L, 18L, 11L, 10L, 21L, 5L, 23L, 
16L, 17L, 22L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 15L, 19L, 14L, 7L, 20L, 12L, 9L, 
13L, 8L), .Label = c("-0,13", "10,13", "10,89", "11,398", "12,48", 
"12,57", "13,11", "14,42", "17,64", "19,04", "20,46", "21,01", 
"2,17", "22,5", "24,94", "26,1", "-3,7", "4,48", "4,83", "5,9", 
"-6,27", "6,63", "-9,14"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(20L, 
16L, 8L, 12L, 18L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 10L, 15L, 19L, 13L, 11L, 22L, 
9L, 4L, 6L, 23L, 17L, 21L, 3L, 14L), .Label = c("38,71", "40,42", 
"41,38", "41,5", "41,89", "43,37", "44,45", "44,82", "45,77", 
"46,52", "47,25", "47,5", "48,36", "50,09", "51,5", "51,92", 
"52,23", "53,34", "54,33", "55,68", "59,86", "60,17", "61,44"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names=                           
c("Kopenhagen","Rotterdam", "Belgrade", "Budapest", "Dublin", "Rome", "Lisbon", 
"Bucharest", "Madrid", "Lausanne", "London", "Kiel", "Augsburg", 
"Innsbruck", "Helsinki", "Lyon", "Ngreece", "Ancona", "Forde", 
"Warsawa", "Uppsala", "Barcelona", "Prague"))
```

and

```
[1]  97.11559  59.86429  25.85145  54.56235  86.00903  17.45889  81.48449
[8]  87.57361  68.49520  44.40894 106.80953  67.36760  77.33586  47.96955
[15]  35.00993  75.26571  43.15965  17.55405  65.85301  46.19634 126.52848
[22]  42.26424  53.29187
```

The first data set called `map` and second called `sigma`.

I write this code:

```
fit<-Krig(map, sigma, theta=100)
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
Error in signif(mat, digits) : 
  Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I do not understand where I am wrong as the organization of my data sets look the same as in the fields package manual.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is some problem with `map`, please update your question with the output of `dput(map)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error because your columns x and y are factor. You must transform a factor to approximately its original numeric values.

```
 map$x <- as.numeric(gsub(",",".", map$x))
 map$y <- as.numeric(gsub(",",".", map$y))
Krig(map, sigma, theta=100)
Call:
Krig(x = dat2, Y = sigma, theta = 100)

 Number of Observations:                23    
 Number of parameters in the null space 3     
 Parameters for fixed spatial drift     3     
 Model degrees of freedom:              19.2  
 Residual degrees of freedom:           3.8   
 GCV estimate for sigma:                9.943 
 MLE for sigma:                         8.931 
 MLE for rho:                           8808  
 lambda                                 0.0091
 User rho                               NA    
 User sigma^2                           NA
```

I don't konw how you had read  map structure , but you can easily avoid teh conversion if you read it as a numeric. for example :

```
map <- read.table(files,sep=',')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand what was the problem. So, I need to change commas to points in my datasets before handling them in R?

Comment: @agstudy the OP doesn't need to substitute, as he's using some Euro locale ("." vs ","), I think, for the decimal separator.    As always, a warning: `as.numeric(as.character(my_factors))` is safer. R-FAQ 7.10

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you're right! But `as.numeric(as.character(my_factors))` will not work for me. I think he must avoid the conversion by reading numeric as numeric not as a factor.

Comment: the OP might try `read.csv2` somewhere upstream, or `read.table(...,dec=",")` ... depending on the file format.